# mat-error doesn't show inside mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mat-select-pykccg?file=app%2Fmy-select.component.ts)

I have mat-select code in a child component and I pass input to show and hide the error. Below here is my code,

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="ctrl" [placeholder]="placeholder">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="onError">Error: Required Field</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The onError is an input property that decides to hide or show the mat error.

Below here is how I call the mat-select

```
<my-select onError="true" [ctrl]="form.get('cities')" [options]="cities" placeholder="Cities"></my-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1.- you forgot say to your component that the select is a `[formControl]`

```
<mat-select [formControl]="ctrl" [placeholder]="placeholder">
    ...
</mat-select>
```

2.- As you pass as `[ctrl]` the own formControl, you needn't implements ControlValueAccessor (this it's used only when you create a custom form control -a "special component" that you can use inside a ReactiveForm or used with [(ngModel)] as a normal `<input>`-. I want to say that **remove** the functions: writeValue, registerOnChange,...

Answer (score 0):

Stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mat-select-nfpb1x?file=app/app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  cities = ['','Krakow', 'Warszawa', 'Gdansk'];
  countries = ['Poland', 'Germany', 'Sweden'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      cities: ['', Validators.required],
      countries: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }
}
```

Just add empty selection because error comes if empty value.

Comment: it works if you put the mat-error outside mat-form-field but not inside it. you don't need the empty string just click any option. it will work

Comment: but this validation is for non selection of valid input right ?

Comment: I will trigger the markastouched method but if its inside the mat-select they dont work

Comment: `cities: ['', Validators.required],` will throw error when there is empty as per this

Comment: my link updated. the problem is with ng value accessor

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to aviby2006s empty, you can also add the empty option in the template, so your options array can stay without the empty option:

```html
<mat-select [formControl]="ctrl" [placeholder]="placeholder">
  <mat-option value=""></mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
     {{ option }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: you don't need an empty option or empty string to make it work. Just click on the select-box and don't select any option.